# Versioning Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, versioning

I have searched around for a couple of days trying to figure out if I am appropriately versioning my rails api. I haven't quite found a good answer that helps me feel comfortable with my current approach. Thus, I have decided to take to stackoverflow to get my fellow Rails mates opinions. Lets look at some code:

I first started out by adding a namespace `:api` with a subdomain of 'api' to my api in `routes.rb`. I also added a scope for `v1`.

```
require 'api_constraints'

HostApi::Application.routes.draw do
  # Api Definition
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/' do
    # Scoping Api Version
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      # resources here
    end
  end
end
```

I want to give those who hit the api to get back the current default version unless they specify a different version through headers. To handle this, I created an `api_constraints` in my lib directory.

`lib/api_constraints.rb` & `lib/spec/api_constraints_spec.rb` for testing.

```
class ApiConstraints

  def initialize(options)
    @version = options[:version]
    @default = options[:default]
  end

  def matches?(request)
    @default || request.headers["Accept"].include?("application/vnd.host_api.v#{@version}")
  end

end
```

My test's pass and everything feels good. What I am curious about is when I start adding version 2,3,4; Can they be scoped the same way as `v1` is scoped? Example:

```
require 'api_constraints'

HostApi::Application.routes.draw do
  # Api Definition
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/' do
    # Scoping Api Version
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1) do
      # resources here
    end
    scope module: :v2, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 2, default: true) do
      # resources here
    end
  end
end
```

I would imagine that changing passing default true to `ApiConstraints` in `v2` scope would now set it as the default response when a version isn't requested through headers. Am I understanding this correctly? Would there be a better approach to handling the version than this? Thoughts, ideas, opinions greatly appreciated.

Side question. I did also change `Rails.application.routes.draw` in the `routes.rb` file, to `HostApi::Application.routes.draw`. This is commonly what I have seen others do, but I am unsure what the benefit to doing this is. If someone could help elaborate I would be very thankful. Thank you in advance for anyone who takes the time to help me understand this or simply share their thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the same `ApiConstraints` in my [rails-api-base](https://github.com/jordifierro/rails-api-base) project and it crashes when you try `matches?` with a non-default version without specifying the `Accept` header.

I added the following case to my tests (which crashes):

```
it 'returns false when not default and no Accept header' do
  request = double(host: 'api.host_api.dev')
  expect(api_constraints_v1.matches?(request)).to be false
end
```

And I fixed `ApiConstraints`:

```
def matches?(req)
  @default ||
    (req.respond_to?('headers') &&
     req.headers.key?('Accept') &&
     req.headers['Accept'].include?("application/vnd.host_api.v#{@version}"))
end
```

Hope it helps!